# Discord.js, message.guild.owner returns null

Tags: discord, discord.js, owner

I'm coding a `server-info` command for my discord bot, and I want to get the owner username or tag from the actual guild. I found a way to do it in discord js 11, but it's not working anymore under 12th version :

```
const guild = client.guilds.get(message.guild.id);
message.channel.send(message.guild.member(guild.owner) ? guild.owner.toString() : guild.owner.user.tag);
// if the user is in that guild it will mention him, otherwise it will use .tag
```

So in discord js 12, `client.guilds.get` isn't a function, and `guild.owner` returns `null`.
`message.guild.owner.user.username`is also returning `Cannot read property 'user' of null`.
I took a look at the documentation, and `message.guild.owner` seems to be a real property (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=owner). So I don't know why it's returning null.

Comment: Did you fix the `client.guilds.get()` function?

Comment: try a `console.log(message.guild)` and see if there is an ownerID.

Comment: @Lioness100, It's now client.guilds.cache.get, but it's not working neither

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca I tried. It's returning all the guild informations. So I changed the `guild`const to `message.guild.id`, but now, `message.guild.id.owner` is undefined

Comment: there should a a value named `ownerID` in the `guild` object. See if you have that. `console.log(message.guild.ownerID)`

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca `message.guild.ownerID` is returning the owner's id. But now, can I get his tag / his username from his ID ?

Comment: yes, it's not ideal but you can use the ID to find the owner. You do that like you would find any other member by ID.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you first get the guild and make sure that it's available before trying to modify or access it. Therefore, your bot won't hit any errors. Additionally, as far as I know, `guild.owner` returns null but there is a way around this. You can get the guild owner ID through `guild.ownerID` and fetch the member as a guildMember. Here is the code:

```js
const guild = message.guild; // Gets guild from the Message object
if(!guild.available) return; // Stops if unavailable
await message.guild.members.fetch(message.guild.ownerID) // Fetches owner
      .then(guildMember => sOwner = guildMember) // sOwner is the owner
message.channel.send(guild.member(sOwner) ? sOwner.toString() : guild.owner.user.tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would get the owner's tag when you have the guild. This also does not rely on the cache, so if your bot restarts or the cache is cleared, it will work regardless.

```js
let ownerTag = undefined;
<client>.users.fetch(<guild>.ownerID).then(user => ownerTag = user.tag);
```

`.fetch()` returns a promise, which is why I declared a variable and then assigned the value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable these intents in your discord developer portal so your bot could access your server

[image: Example to enable intent]

After that, you could access your user owner tag.